# How do I fix the "Type GraphComponent in /node_modules/<filepath> is part of the declarations of 2 modules" error in Angular?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an angular project using the AOT build mode:

```
ng build --prod
```

When I run build with the `--prod` switch, I receive the following error:

```
 ERROR in : Cannot determine the module for class GraphComponent in 
 C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication
 /node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/src/graph/graph.component.ts! Add 
 GraphComponent to the NgModule to fix it.
```

I followed its instructions and added `GraphComponent` to the `NgModule`:

```
 ERROR in : Type GraphComponent in 
 C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon
 /CRMApplication/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx- graph/release/graph
 /graph.component.d.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules:
 GraphModule in C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/
CRMApplication/node_modules/@swimlane/ngxgraph/release/graph
/graph.module.d.ts and AppModule in C:/Users/yassine/Documents/
NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication/src/app/app.module.ts! Please
consider moving GraphComponent in C:/Users/yassine/Documents/Net
BeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx- 
graph/release/graph/graph.component.d.ts to a higher module that imports 
GraphModule in 
C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication
/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/release/graph/gr
aph.module.d.ts and AppModule in 
C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication
/src/app/app.module.ts. You can also create a new NgModule that exports 
 and includes GraphComponent in 
C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication
/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/release/graph/graph.component.d.ts then 
import that NgModule in GraphModule in 
C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon/CRMApplication
/node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-graph/release/graph/graph.module.d.ts and 
 AppModule in C:/Users/yassine/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Horizon
 /CRMApplication/src/app/app.module.ts.
```

It looks like in the dependency chain, `GraphComponent` is getting imported twice:

```
             imports        declares
NgxGraphModule -> GraphModule -> GraphComponent with the some name GraphComponent, when i loocked up i found that i'm importing NgxGraphModule who import GraphModule who declare GraphComponent.
```

I have a `src` and `release` folder with duplicate files. I believe the `release` is created as a build artifact.

Here is the declaration of my `GraphComponent`; I am unclear how to fix this build error in AOT Build mode. How do I resolve this error?

```
 import {NgxGraphModule} from '@swimlane/ngx-graph';
 import {GraphComponent} from "@swimlane/ngx- 
 graph/release/graph/graph.component";

 const appRoutes:Routes=[
 {
    path:'',component: ClientComponent
  },
 {
    path:'contact',component: ContactComponent
 }
];

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
    GraphComponent
   ],
   imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),NgxGraphModule
   ],
   // providers: [Principale],
   //providers: [{ provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'fr' }],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
 })

 export class AppModule {

  }
```

Comment: What third party component are you using that also uses graphmodule? Is it `@swimlane`?

Comment: graphmodule existe in two differente place in thie labrary

Comment: in the `Swimlane` module?

Comment: yes Swimlane say that we must import only NgxGraphModule and all others compenents will be there but that don't happen